spresenseのサブコアを利用してros1と通信出来ていません
現在spresenseをrosserialを利用してros1で通信しています．通信遅延改善のためrosとトピックの送受信するプログラムをサブコアに記述して通信しようとしたら，通信出来なくなってしまいました．現在原因が分からず探しているところなのですが，そもそもサブコアでros1と通信することが出来るのかが分からなかったため，もし可能かどうかを知っていらっしゃる方がいれば教えていただきたいです．よろしくお願いします．
シングルコアで動いていたプログラムをマルチコアに分解して再度実施したらトピックのやり取りが出来なくなりました．まだマルチコアについてあまり詳しくないため，自分の記述したプログラムが原因なのかそもそもサブコアでは出来ないのかがまだ把握できていません．
現在，作成したマルチコアのプログラム自体は最後まで実行されていることをLEDの点灯で確認しました．

プログラム次第ですが、サブコアではC標準関数ライブラリなどの使用に制限があるので、メインコアのプログラムそのものが動くとは限らないです。 includeしているヘッダファイルが何かとか、コードが見えないとアドバイスしようがないと思います。
